# How secure is the CodeIgniter framework?

Tags: web-development

I want to develop a website using the CodeIgniter framework. I'm just worried about the security of the framework. Is there an issue or event that a website is being hacked that uses CodeIgniter framework?

Comment: As secure as your own code is. Anything "secure" can become insecure if misused or improperly handled by unqualified person (and CodeIgniter is not an exception).

Answer (score 4):

CodeIgniter is safe to use as it is in active development and any security issues discovered are quickly patched.

However, this doesn't mean if you use CodeIgniter that your code will automatically be safe. The CodeIgniter codebase may be safe but you can still write unsafe code with it. This is true of any framework. You still need to know how to code defensively to prevent an attacker from exploiting your system.

Comment: conde | Thanks.. (sigh) : ) All i need to do is to code defensively..thanks!

Comment: Adding to this, some of the best functionality available in CodeIgniter comes from the community (ex: Tank Auth). You have to pay close attention to how the libraries that you add to the framework are written to maintain secuirty. Usually the codeigniter forum is a good place to review feedback on any given library.